# Pyinstaller throws "No module named multipart", "No module named image","No module named text","No module named message"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm creating a installable package for my webapp (flask) using pyinstaller. (pyinstaller app.py)
after creating the package, i start running the application (dist->app)

it throws "import error text"

Answer (score 1):

the below command to create an application package.

i have imported all the import error to application file as mentioned below.

```
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.message import MIMEMessage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
```

it is fixed the import problem